# Magento 2 : How to debug knockoutjs getRegion() bindings

Tags: magento2, layout, knockoutjs, jslayout

**Shipping address** is displayed using below **knockout js** code.
I am having a hard time finding the back-end code that's setting data for `getRegion('ship-to')` function even though I could see the UI JS template component configuration. Does anyone have any input on how this data is being pulled on the payment/review page in Magento 2.x?

```
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('ship-to') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() -->
    <!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: Please check my answer and do let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 6):

```
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('ship-to') -->
```

invokes the following piece of code from `checkout_index_index.xml` layout file

```
<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shipping-information</item>
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="ship-to" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information/list</item>
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">ship-to</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

It essentially asks to load uiComponent corresponding to the region i.e `Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information/list` and loop and render through all its children.

```
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() -->
```

renders HTML templates corresponding to each component, you can know template for a uiComponent by looking into its code. For eg. for current uiComponent i.e 
`Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/list.js` following code tells us that  the template for it is `Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/list.html` located under `view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address` directory.

```
return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/list',
            visible: addressList().length > 0,
            rendererTemplates: []
        },
```

All the addresses are maintained in a global  js window object called `customerData`, if you specifically want to know how data is coming from php. This [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237697/magento-2-from-where-php-is-the-checkout-billing-address-options-drop-down-b) of mine might help.

Please feel free to ask any questions.

Answer (score 1):

**shipping-information.html** checkout template is being pulled by:

> `vendor > magento > module-checkout > view > frontend > web > js > view > shipping-information.js`

If you will notice, in that template there is a class **`shipping-information-content`** under the class **`ship-via`** wherein data are bind from **`shipping-information.js`** method.

EDIT:
**ship-to** data are pulled from shipping information address renderer. Check this template file:

> `vendor > magento > module-checkout > view > frontend > web > template > shipping-information > address-renderer > default.html`

Comment: thanks for the response. I do see the template and shipping-information.js. There I don't see any methods for getting 'ship-to' region/component data but I do see `getShippingMethodTitle(), backtoShippingMethod()`, and `back()` functions. Am I missing anything here since I don't see 'ship-to' view model?

Comment: I can't check it for now because I'm using a mobile phone. but as far as I know, the ship-to region pertains to the block where shipping-information contents will bind and be displayed

Comment: when I say block, I mean to say is a div block

Comment: I grepped for 'ship-to' under `vendor/` and `app/` and don't see it anywhere else other than `/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` and in `shipping-information.html`. Not sure which view-model is getting this data.

Comment: ah it is with the address renderer

Comment: what is your goal about this? do you plan to override the ship-to block?

Comment: My issue is try to understand why and how 'ship-to' component gets different data in below mentioned scenario. Can you check this and let me know since ultimately this is the issue I am trying to solve? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267160/force-quote-address-instead-of-customer-address-when-browser-is-refreshed-magent

Comment: I have seen it, do you have custom module or extension that overrides the checkout page or part of it?

Comment: There is some custom code to update quote_address table with selected shipping address, but the refresh appears to load customer address from somewhere else, any idea on how it gets that address data in both cases?

Comment: Thanks for checking again. I checked `vendor > magento > module-checkout > view > frontend > web > template > shipping-information > address-renderer > default.html` and I do see address data but there is no ko code to get 'ship-to' region data there. Which view model or Observable is used to get this data?