# Magento 2 : Which view model or Observable pulls shipping address data on payment page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, knockoutjs

I see that following code from `shipping-information` template is used to display shipping address on checkout#payment page but unable to understand which Magento 2 PhP Model or knockout view model is getting this data. I know that this data comes from address tables but what I would like to understand is the middle man that's getting the data since I see the DB table and fronte-end code, but not the code that's fetching it.

```
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('ship-to') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() -->
    <!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

Any clues gurus?

Alan Storm has a good to post to understand what's going on from shipping to payment page, which is very helpful in case anyone needs it.

[Magento 2 checkout - Shipping to Payment](https://alanstorm.com/more-magento-2-checkout-notes-shipping-to-payment/)

Comment: I hope it helps! https://inviqa.com/blog/using-knockout-js-magento-2

Comment: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/knockoutjs-in-magento-2/

Comment: Thanks Chirag. I read through above posts and I do understand how knockoutjs bindings are working for given examples, but I don't see similar code for this Magento 2 scenario. Am I missing anything? Please comment if you know OOB Magento 2 code that's responsible for this since I couldn't find it.

Comment: Do you want to know how template binding works in general or its core implementation?

Comment: I would like to know where to find the implementation for 'ship-to' address view model code in OOB Magento 2.2.x code to fix a bug we have when displaying the shipping address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('ship-to') -->
```

invokes the following piece of code from `checkout_index_index.xml` layout file

```
<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shipping-information</item>
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="ship-to" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information/list</item>
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">ship-to</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

It essentially asks to load uiComponent corresponding to the region i.e `Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information/list` and loop and render through all its children.

```
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() -->
```

renders HTML templates corresponding to each component, you can know template for a uiComponent by looking into its code. For eg. for current uiComponent i.e 
`Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/list.js` following code tells us that  the template for it is `Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/list.html` located under `view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address` directory.

```
return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/list',
            visible: addressList().length > 0,
            rendererTemplates: []
        },
```

Please feel free to ask any questions.

**EDIT :**

All the addresses are maintained in a global  js window object called `customerData`, if you specifically want to know how data is coming from php. This [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237697/magento-2-from-where-php-is-the-checkout-billing-address-options-drop-down-b) of mine might help.

Comment: this is great information, I kind of got it but my understanding is much better now. At the end what I am trying to understand is the helper or Block that's getting 'ship-to' address information from the DB. Any idea on which code is doing in OOB Magento 2 code?

Comment: the linked Q&A certainly helped to understand OOB Magento address flow. Here is the issue I am running into https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267160/force-quote-address-instead-of-customer-address-when-browser-is-refreshed-magent, any idea on how to extend customerdata address data for this scenario to display quote address data instead of customer address book addresses when browser is refreshed?

Comment: tried few things but still unable to find root cause for the refresh issue.